# $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n^2}E(\sqrt{k})\quad n\in\mathbb{N}^{*}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

I found in my archives solution of this exercise

Calculate
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n^2}E(\sqrt{k})\quad n\in\mathbb{N}^{*}$$

$E$ represents the floor function
Solution:

they made

Let $S_{n}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n^2}E(\sqrt{k})$

we've
\begin{align*}
S_{n}&=1+\sum_{2}^{3}1+\sum_{4}^{8}2+\sum_{9}^{15}3+\sum_{16}^{24}4+\ldots+\sum_{(n-1)^{2}}^{n^2-1}+n\\
&=1+2.1+5.2+7.3+9.4+\ldots +(2n-1)(n-1)+n\\
&=[\sum_{k=1}^{n}(2k-1)(k-1)]+n\\
&=[\sum_{k=1}^{n}2k^2-3k+1]+n\\
&=2\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2+-3\sum_{k=1}^{n}k+\sum_{k=1}^{n}1+n
\end{align*}

My question i didn't understand how they get this expression and the idea behind it ( is it Change of variables and if its why ):
$$S_{n}=1+\sum_{2}^{3}1+\sum_{4}^{8}2+\sum_{9}^{15}3+\sum_{16}^{24}4+\ldots+\sum_{(n-1)^{2}}^{n^2-1}+n$$

I tried to develop the series, but I do not find the same result and what is its role

by the way one of my friend told me $[(j-1)^2;j^2-1]$ but i can see why and how get this idea

how can i go from $1\leq K \leq n^2$ to get that $E(\sqrt{k})=j \iff j^2 \le k < (j+1)^2$ can you elaborate that

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: By $E$ you mean floor?

Comment: yes the floor function

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $\lfloor \sqrt x\rfloor=k$ for $k^2\leq x<(k+1)^2$.

$\def\F#1{\lfloor #1\rfloor}$
It means:
\begin{align}
&\sqrt{1}+(\F{\sqrt{2}}+\F{\sqrt{3}})+(\F{\sqrt{4}}+\F{\sqrt{5}}+\F{\sqrt{6}}+\F{\sqrt{7}}+\F{\sqrt{8}})+\dots\\
&\quad =1+(1+1)+(2+2+2+2+2)+\dots=\\
&\quad= 1+\sum_{2}^{3}1+\sum_{4}^{8}2+\dots
\end{align}

Comment: I need detailed explanation already have solution no need to hint

Comment: @Educ Is a little bit extended version om my answer enough?

Comment: how can i go from $1\leq k \leq n^2$ to get that $E(\sqrt{k})=j \iff j^2 \le k < (j+1)^2$ can you elaborate that

Comment: @Educ $E(\sqrt{k^2})=k$ and $E(x)$ remains $k$ until $x=(k+1)^2$ (the smallest number, which square is equal to the next natural number) -- from de definition of floor.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that $E(\sqrt{k}) = j$ iff $j^2 \le k < (j+1)^2$.  So there are
$(j+1)^2 - j^2$ terms where the summand is $j$.

Comment: how can i go from $1\leq k \leq n^2$ to get that $E(\sqrt{k})=j \iff j^2 \le k < (j+1)^2$ can you elaborate that